# How do I optimize loading a lot of Strings in my android app?

Tags: android, xml, performance, data-structures

I'm currently working on a project where I have a dictionary list of words of the english language. I use this list to figure out if a user has inputted a valid word. The whole list is rather lengthy, were talking about 100k of Strings, but I have partitioned the list into smaller bits. These files are stored as xml files and are accessed by the assetmanager. I use the parser as such to open the file:

document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

The document is a Document object using the library: org.w3c.dom.Document

So the problem is that this actually slows down the app A LOT, even with the smaller partitioned files (in fact initially I just had one file with all the 100k Strings and it crashed the app immediately). So should I use text files instead? Or instead of using the assetmanager should I store my data in resources? Or any other way to optimize speed for that matter? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Im actualy looking to fix the same issue. I load 180 textviews in the same view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not store the word list in an [sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) table?  You get indexed-based searches.  If each entry is one word then a normal table is fine.  If you are using multiple words per entry, then an [fts table](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)  (full-text-search) solution would be best.

If speed is paramount (i.e. you don't care how much memory you use up -- which would be very unusual for an android app), then loading the words into a [hashtable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Hashtable.html) would probably give you the fastest per word lookup.  It would take some time to load the list on startup, however.

Comment: I'm gonna try the sqlite table see if its fast enough, thanks for the response

Comment: Here's some performance metrics for the FTS table (using the Enron Email dataset - 517,000+ documents) https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1

Answer (score 1):

So I was playing around with different approaches and found out that instead of using partitioned xml files, I used text files saved in the asset folder which greatly reduced execution time.

Comment: Did it optimize the loading by a great deal or should i use sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a big traitement to deal with and you this my make your apps slow, i recommande you to use **AsyncTask** so that you can do what ever you want in backGround and meanwhile you can do another thing, take a look in this [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)